# Azure cosmos db support in Arabic, Japanese, Chinese ,Arabic, Spanish, French CRUD

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm exploring cosmos db, so just one question if any one has done such multiple language data storing and CRUD operation for cosmos db. How to do that? I didn't find any documentation in Azure if such multi-language supports and process/sample code for it. Any help guide, please.

Answer (score 0):

We store a single document for all languages.  An example being products that have titles and descriptions.  Within that document any property that needs to be translatable, ie its customer facing, is set to use a custom class we developed called `LocalizeString`.

There is nothing special about our CRUD operations.  Been using this approach for several years and its worked fairly well.  HTH.

**Here is the custom class:**

```
public class LocalizedString
    {
        public const string DefaultLanugage = "en";
        public const string French = "fr";
        public const string German = "de";
        public const string Italian = "it";
        public const string Portuguese = "pt";
        public const string Spanish = "es";

        public LocalizedString()
        {
            Translations = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }

        public static Dictionary<string, string> AvailableLanguages = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { DefaultLanugage, "English" },
            { Spanish, "Spanish" },
            { French, "French" },
            { Italian, "Italian" },
            { Portuguese, "Portuguese" },
            { German, "German" }
        };

        public LocalizedString(string value, string lanuage = DefaultLanugage)
        {
            Translations = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { lanuage, value }
            };
        }

        public Dictionary<string, string> Translations { get; set; }

        public string GetValue(string language = DefaultLanugage)
        {
            if (Translations.ContainsKey(language))
            {
                return Translations[language];
            }

            if (Translations.ContainsKey(DefaultLanugage))
            {
                return Translations[DefaultLanugage];
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }

        public static LocalizedString SetValue(LocalizedString item, string value, string lanuage = DefaultLanugage)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                item = new LocalizedString();
            }

            if (item.Translations.ContainsKey(lanuage))
            {
                item.Translations[lanuage] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                item.Translations.Add(lanuage, value);
            }

            return item;
        }

        public static List<CultureInfo> SupportedCultures => AvailableLanguages.Select(x => new CultureInfo(x.Key)).ToList();
    }
```

**Usage looks like this:**

```
public class Product
{
    public LocalizedString Description { get; set; }
    ...
}

 // Setting the value
item.Description = LocalizedString.SetValue(item.Description, model.TranslatedVersion.Description, model.SelectedLanugage);
 // Getting the value
item.Description.GetValue(request.SelectedLanguage)
```

**This is what the json looks like:**

```
"Description": {
                "Translations": {
                    "en": "Standard",
                    "es": "Estándar"
                }
            }
```